# Django - Create user profile on user creation

Tags: django, django-registration, user-profile

I'm following Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) in order to achieve a simple objective: Create a user profile as soon as a new user is created.

I have an 'accounts' app and my accounts.models looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from main.models import Store

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    GENRE_CHOICES = (
        ('m', 'Masculino'),
        ('f', 'Feminino'),
    )
    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('s', 'Solteiro'),
        ('c', 'Casado'),
        ('d', 'Divorciado'),
        ('v', 'Viúvo'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postal_code_4 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    postal_code_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    locatity = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    child_amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, null=True)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Everything looks fine to me but when trying to add a new user (using django admin), instead of having a newly created user and user profile, I get the following error:
**InternalError at /admin/auth/user/add/
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block**

Here is the traceback error part:

```
/djangoProjects/lwboanova/lwboanova/apps/accounts/models.py in create_user_profile

34: UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

It seems like an integrity error but I'm not getting the reason for it.

Would be great if any of ya could give me some help on this.

Comment: Do you have the django toolbar installed ? If so try disabling it so that you get better error info.

Comment: I am surprised to see some answers using `instance.profile.save()` even after `UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)`. Looks like everyone is following the same old blog! AFAIK, `create` calls `save` implicitly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just figured it out.

I forgot to add `null=True` to the rest of `UserProfile` model fields.

So the `accounts.models.UserProfile` fields now looks like:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
genre = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENRE_CHOICES, null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
postal_code_4 = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
postal_code_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
locatity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES, null=True)
child_amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
store = models.ForeignKey(Store, null=True)
```

...and everything is working as intended!

Cheers for trying to help Ashray ^^

Comment: ,can you please check and guide me, SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806683/create-row-of-date-while-creating-superuser

Comment: Hi, could you post what does your views.py file looks like ?

Answer (score 19):

You shouldn't use:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

Instead use this:

```
from django.conf import settings
..
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Comment: You're right about the OneToOneField, but a relation to the User model is fine. That is, if you extend the build in User with additional fields. Only use the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting if you want to replace the build in User model with your own.

Comment: @allcaps Last sentence is misleading. `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a way to protect this piece of code from a regression bug if hardcoded `User` is no longer the model in the future.

Answer (score 6):

You can create this using Django Signals. Reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/

Add this to installed_apps in settings.py

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    ...

]
```

Note: if you use `accounts` in INSTALLED_APPS, you'll have to initialise in **init**.py

In models.py remove create_user_profile

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from main.models import Store

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    GENRE_CHOICES = (
        ('m', 'Masculino'),
        ('f', 'Feminino'),
    )
    MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('s', 'Solteiro'),
        ('c', 'Casado'),
        ('d', 'Divorciado'),
        ('v', 'Viúvo'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postal_code_4 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    postal_code_3 = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    locatity = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MARITAL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    child_amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, null=True)
```

Add create_user_profile in signals.py

```
# signals.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import UserProfile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Finally,  edit apps.py

```
# apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'

    def ready(self):
        import accounts.signals
```

Comment: I love this answer, It should marked as resolved. Thank you!

Comment: Should the end of your third codeblock be `instance.userprofile.save()`? I'm having a strange issue where my version of `.profile` (or `.userprofile`, as it were) is causing an AttributeError.

Answer (score 3):

```
def create_profile(sender,**kwargs ):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile=UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=User)
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: This needs more details about why it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.profile.save()
```

Like this it will be easy to read code.

Comment: could you add some explanation to this answer that make this answer stand out from the others?

Answer (score 1):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('created', True) and not kwargs.get('raw', False):
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

I had success trying this method

```
def create_profile(sender,**kwargs ):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile=UserProfile(user=kwargs['instance'])
        user_profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```