# Django Boolean Field used in view.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a feature to where a new user needs to update his/her password on an initial login. I added a hidden BooleanField to my Profile model where default = True.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    force_password_change = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

However, when trying to use force_password_change in my views.py, it never returns the correct value that I set in django's admin page.

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    changepass = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if user:
        if changepass.force_password_change == True:
            changepass.force_password_change = False
            changepass.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/register/')
        elif changepass.force_password_change == False:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account has been disabled.")
```

It is currently giving me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 
   41, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, 
   in _get_response
   response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, 
   in _get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "start\views.py", line 20, in user_login
   changepass = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, 
   in manager_method
   return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 380, in 
   get
   self.model._meta.object_name
   start.models.DoesNotExist: UserProfile matching query does not exist.
```

I also added `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'start.UserProfile'` to my settings.py, so that does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: When you created your user did you specifically created UserProfile with the user object.

Comment: I created my user through the admin page that comes with django. I am using UserProfile to add fields to that.

Comment: You need to write a post_save method for admin site on User object creation. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488974/django-create-user-profile-on-user-creation

Comment: Hey thank you for that! I just added the create_user_profile code. Seems like that problem is gone. Thank you.

Comment: Do upvote comment and  Welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to create UserProfile with the respected user

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uf = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='user')
        upf = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='userprofile')
        if uf.is_valid() and upf.is_valid():
            user = uf.save()
            userprofile = upf.save(commit=False)
            userprofile.user = user
            userprofile.save() # Are you missing this line ??
            return django.http.HttpResponseRedirect(…something…)
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with boolean fields. The error is telling you that your specific User does not have a related entry in the UserProfile table.

Comment: Sorry I changed some things around before posting. How would I go about fixing my current error? I have the user in the django admin page users table.