# Django - perform action on Profile while creating User

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I was looking for solution for my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488974/django-create-user-profile-on-user-creation), but it didnt solve my problem.

I want to create user's profile while their signing up.
To signup I use `CreateView`

```
class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    #this method doesn't work and I get 
    # `Profile.user" must be a "User" instance`

    def form_valid(self,form):
        Profile.objects.create(user=self.request.user)
```

My Profile model looks like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #rest of fields like bio, social urls etc
```

My main point is to automatically create user's profile when their create their account.
What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Best way? I would suggest going with signals as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57349227/4626254

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - Create user profile on user creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488974/django-create-user-profile-on-user-creation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to avoid using signals, since you have a form.

self.request.user will return an user object only when an user is logged in using any form of authentication (Session, token etc.)

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    user = form.save()
    Profile.objects.create(user=user)
    return super(UserRegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: can you explain the last line?